# Unity Hololnes2 camera setting with vuforia, just show webcam

Tags: vuforia, hololens

I am using unity version 2021.3.23f1 and newwest vuforia engine. When I use camera setting (using MRTK add scene feature and vuforia behaviour script, in play mode with remoting app it just show me webcam stream. My world center Mode is slected by "Device", and I don't see any option in setting of script to select Hololens as an option. Everything works fine when it get build and run in Visual Studio but it waste time when I am developing content constantly.
Does anyone face such issue and find a solution for it?

Thanks

this is screen shot of camera setting

[image: camera setting]

and these are assets in the project

[image: assests of project]

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the HoloLens camera in Play Mode, because when in Play Mode, the project runs on the local machine and then only streams the images to the HoloLens device. This is by design.